# No ajax output in my application

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I am trying to post back selected items from a ajax search function inside a table. my post function works well it has a 200 ok status in my firebug network ang this is what it posts back in my html: null {"sp":null,"serviceprovider ":null} and response: null {"sp":null,"serviceprovider ":null}. on my application I am receiving nothing. here is my code that I call it with

Controller

```
public function postserviceproviderAction()

    {
        $form = new Form_IndustrialTable();       
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if(!$form->isValid($_POST)) 
        {
             $values=$form->getValues();
        }

        $sp = $this->getRequest()->getPost('serviceprovider', null); //problem lies here I think


        $mdlserviceprovider = new Model_ServiceProviders();
        $serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($sp);


        $rtn_array= array('serviceprovider ' => $serviceprovider);       


         $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
         $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        echo Zend_Json::encode($rtn_array);
    }
```

model

```
public function getName($id)
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->where('service_provider_id = ?', $id);

        var_dump($mdlserviceprovider);
        return $result['service_provider_name'];
    }
```

phtml

```
$('#add1').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                       url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/ajax/postserviceprovider',
                       type:'post',
                       dataType: "json",
                       data:{   'serviceprovider':$('#service_provider_name').val()},       
                       success:function(data){
                         var row = '<tr><td>' + data["serviceprovider"] + '</td></tr>';
                         $('#t1').append(row);
                        //alert();  
                      }               
                  });
                });
```

HTML Table

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 0;">
<table class='spreadsheet dataTable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='' id="t1">
<thead> 

<tr role="row">
<th>ENTER SERVICE PROVIDER USED</th>

</tr>

<td><?php echo $this->form2->search;?></td>
</thead>    
</table>
<input id='add1' align="right" type="button" name='Add' value="+Add"></input>   
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sp = $this->getRequest()->getParam('serviceprovider');
```

Optionally with in ajax:

```
data: 'serviceprovider=' + $("#service_provider_name").val(),
```

Comment: from your code, you do not declare 'service_provider_name' in the HTML, so you should have null in $ sp

Comment: I am getting undefined, this is what im getting in my html null

null

{"serviceprovider ":null}  and response <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>{"serviceprovider ":null}

Comment: the value of $this->getRequest()->getParam('serviceprovider') should be "undefined", no?

Comment: Im suppose to get ther service provider name from its table

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. You not defined 'service_provider_name' in your html, so $this->getRequest()->getParam('serviceprovider') = 'undefined' so $sp = 'undefined', so, it do $mdlserviceprovider ->getName('undefined');, so it do $select->where('service_provider_id = ?', 'undefied'); no?

Comment: What do you mean doy?

Comment: I said I did not understand the problem.
My English is far from perfect and translations by google are not necessarily appropriate. :)
So I do not understand what the problem is.
If you do not define element 'service_provider_name' in HTML, it is normal that the getName method returns nothing.

That is var_dump ($ this-> getRequest () -> getParams ()) in your controller? (Furthermore, I saw that you did a var_dump ($ mdlserviceprovider) in getName without defining.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, should the code not be re-written as (or similar to):

```
if ( $form->isValid($_POST) ) 
{
    $values = $form->getValues();
    $sp = (!empty(values['serviceprovider']) ? values['serviceprovider'] : '';
    if (!empty($sp)) {
        $mdlserviceprovider = new Model_ServiceProviders();
        $serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($sp);
        $rtn_array= array('serviceprovider ' => $serviceprovider);
    }
}
```

It seems odd to attempt to retrieve values from a form, using the POST super global, if the form wasn't valid. Keen to get your feedback.